# Connecting maps into react-native app

Tags: react-native

I have some API of maps (2GIS). Maps on JS. How can I connect them to my app on react-native? 
I tried to find some possible ways, but without result. I am a newbie on react-native

Comment: What do you mean by "Maps on JS"? What is this API? Is it a map with a UI?

Comment: Yes, map with UI. It is a map like Google Maps, but more developed in my region. You can see it on http://info.2gis.com/index_en.html                                 I don't know how to integrate maps. API is given on JS

Comment: You'll don't understand - use translate  -> http://api.2gis.ru/doc/maps/quickstart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a native component that nobody wrote a `React Native` component for, you will to do it yourself.

It's not very hard for most things. You can learn how to do it for [iOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) and [Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html) in the linked docs.

Comment: Thanks! I will try